# How to check if a value in the list exists in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

Got a data frame that has 5 columns and a list that contains 20 values.

if the value in the list exactly matches any value in the columns then it has to append the value (list value) to an empty column.

```
list=["siper","glock","tip",............]
```

INPUT (DATAFRAME ) DF1:

[image: Dataframe]

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image: Dataframe]

My code to check if the value in the list exist in data frame.

```
list=["siper","glock","tip",............]
df2=[]
for i in list:
  mask=np.column_stack([df[col]==i for col in df])
  df2.append(df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)])
```

The above code gives a list of all rows in the data frame if the value in the list matches any column but I am not sure how to append values in the list to column1 if there is any match. Also, I want to add "Unknow" to column1 if there is no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.extract`:

```
lst = ['glock', 'siper']

df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(fr"\b({'|'.join(lst)})\b")
                              .bfill().iloc[0].fillna('unknown'), axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
                  A                B                       C        D
0            lfkdjs            siper              ldjkslkdjq    siper
1  the glock hammer     ldksqjflsdkj            dljkfdslkfjs    glock
2     lfdkslkdfjsdl    dflskjfsdlkjf                  tipper  unknown
3     fdlsjkfsldkjf  dlfjksdflkdsjfs  The glockmaster hammer  unknown
```

Comment: Almost. But the issue is if one of the columns has "The glockmaster hammer" and the list has=["glock"]. Your solution would still assign glock to column D. I want to assign glock only if the list and string in any of the columns has the same word.

Comment: I updated my answer: I changed my regex with `\b` (word boundary). I also changed my sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['column1'] = np.array(['unknown', *l])[np.max([df.apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(item)).mul(i+1).sum(axis=1) for i, item in enumerate(list)], axis=0)]
```

Comment: does list=item in my case?

Comment: I update the answer, check now.

Comment: Lol, yeah, funny! You did it again in your answer :) (Which by the way is better than mine)

Comment: what is item in this solution? because I am getting "item" is not defined?

Comment: `item` is a variable returned from `enumerate(list)`